# creating own application using ws4py

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, ws4py

I have created a web server socket using ws4py and which uses cherrypy.  When I connect to the server using `ip:port` it connects perfectly and am able to chat through multiple browsers. However when I try to connect `ip:port/ws` it also works.

However, after I connect without using the `ws`, I am unable to handshake.  I want to handle all request from client browser or it may another from different sources like using c# by this url `ip:port/app` and send payload from the client.

I have installed ws4py by this command `sudo pip install ws4py` and my server script is:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import random
import os

import cherrypy

from ws4py.server.cherrypyserver import WebSocketPlugin, WebSocketTool
from ws4py.websocket import WebSocket
from ws4py.messaging import TextMessage

class ChatWebSocketHandler(WebSocket):
    def received_message(self, m):
        print "Message Received---------------------1"
        print m
        cherrypy.engine.publish('websocket-broadcast', m)

    def closed(self, code, reason="A client left the room without a proper explanation."):
        print "Socket Closed---------------------2"
        cherrypy.engine.publish('websocket-broadcast', TextMessage(reason))

class Root(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port, ssl=False):
        print "Rooot host "+str(host)+ " Port "+str(port)+ " -----------3"
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.scheme = 'wss' if ssl else 'ws'

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
    <head>
      <script type='application/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='application/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {

          websocket = '%(scheme)s://%(host)s:%(port)s/ws';
          if (window.WebSocket) {
            ws = new WebSocket(websocket);
          }
          else if (window.MozWebSocket) {
            ws = MozWebSocket(websocket);
          }
          else {
            console.log('WebSocket Not Supported');
            return;
          }

          window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + 'Bye bye...\\n');
            ws.close(1000, '%(username)s left the room');

            if(!e) e = window.event;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          };
          ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
             $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + evt.data + '\\n');
          };
          ws.onopen = function() {
             ws.send("%(username)s entered the room");
          };
          ws.onclose = function(evt) {
             $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + 'Connection closed by server: ' + evt.code + ' \"' + evt.reason + '\"\\n');
          };

          $('#send').click(function() {
             console.log($('#message').val());
             ws.send('%(username)s: ' + $('#message').val());
             $('#message').val("");
             return false;
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='#' id='chatform' method='get'>
      <textarea id='chat' cols='35' rows='10'></textarea>
      <br />
      <label for='message'>%(username)s: </label><input type='text' id='message' />
      <input id='send' type='submit' value='Send' />
      </form>

      HI ****************************************************************************

    </body>
    </html>
    """ % {'username': "User%d" % random.randint(0, 100), 'host': self.host, 'port': self.port, 'scheme': self.scheme}

    @cherrypy.expose
    def ws(self):
        print ("request for ws------------------------------------------------------4")
        cherrypy.log("Handler created: %s" % repr(cherrypy.request.ws_handler))

    @cherrypy.expose
    def App(self):
        print ("request for App---------------------------------------------5")
        cherrypy.log("Handler created: %s" % repr(cherrypy.request.ws_handler))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    from ws4py import configure_logger
    configure_logger(level=logging.DEBUG)

    print " Start Main ----------------------------------------------0"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Echo CherryPy Server')
    parser.add_argument('--host', default='192.x.x.x')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=yyyy, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--ssl', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': args.host,
                            'server.socket_port': args.port,
                            'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))})

    if args.ssl:
        cherrypy.config.update({'server.ssl_certificate': './server.crt',
                                'server.ssl_private_key': './server.key'})

    WebSocketPlugin(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()
    cherrypy.tools.websocket = WebSocketTool()

    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(args.host, args.port, args.ssl), '', config={
        '/ws': {
            'tools.websocket.on': True,
            'tools.websocket.handler_cls': ChatWebSocketHandler
            },
        '/js': {
              'tools.staticdir.on': True,
              'tools.staticdir.dir': 'js'
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Hai meawoppl I am happy as You rectify my grammar if you solve my problem i'll more heappy

Answer (score 0):

Could you precsie what you mean by:

> However, after I connect whithot using the ws, I am unable to handshake.

Do you mean you can't use the server at all afterwards? As a remainder, you can only perform websocket upgrade on the /ws path here since that's how you configured it at the bottom of your snippet.

Comment: Hai @Sylvain Hellegouarch thanks for your reply
I had did it by using gevent