# read TextMessage ws4py on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy, ws4py

I have created a web server socket using ws4py 0.3.2 and which uses cherrypy 3.2.4 on python 3.3.2 .When I try to print Message of client send to server like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748374/creating-own-appplication-using-ws4py)

```
class ChatWebSocketHandler(WebSocket):
    def received_message(self, m):
        cherrypy.log("[+] Message => {%d} %s" % (len(m), m))
        cherrypy.engine.publish('websocket-broadcast', m)
```

I got error message :

```
  File "./server.py", line 13, in received_message
    cherrypy.log("[+] Message => {%d} %s" % (len(m), m))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Comment: Replace `cherrypy.log("[+] Message => {%d} %s" % (len(m), m))` with `cherrypy.log("[+] Message => {%d} %r" % (len(m), m))`. Then what happen?

Comment: output off `cherrypy.log("[+] Message => {%d} %r" % (len(m), m))` is:

`[+] Message => {46} <ws4py.messaging.TextMessage object at 0x7f15d8785650>`

Answer (score 4):

The returned object is of type TextMessage or BinaryMessage, so you can't cast it to a string directly. To get to the payload (string, in this case) you need to access the data attribute:

Like this:

```
def received_message(self, m):
  if m.is_text:
    recvStr = m.data.decode("utf-8")
    print(recvStr)
```

Hope this is usable.